# Cохраняет бот id моего Teleram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

пишу вам с таким интересующим меня вопросом.
Если я писала в бот тех.подержки интернет-магазина, в боте сохраняется id-Teleram
как и сам текст переписки?

И ещё, можно ли в самом боте найти кусок сообщения которое писала, и посмотреть какому пользователю с каким id в телеграмме, принадлежит это сообщение.

Comment: Я не изучал python, но мне кажется, что ваш вопрос слишком общий. То сеть он включает в себя несколько вопросов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Все сохраняется в базу данных. Ваш id и ваше сообщение. Структуры баз бывают разные, но в основном сохраняют практически всю информацию о пользователе и его сообщениях. Соответственно при желании хозяин(админ) базы(бота) может все это достать.